# Cannot Download simple CSV stream from laravel response using Google Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, laravel, streaming, httpresponse

When I go the `/test-csv` route in Safari/Firefox, I am able to download the one-line csv file.  But when I try it in Chrome, it says 'Failed to load Response Data' in the Network tab of the console.

```
*edit*
```

IMPORTANT NEW DETAIL:  It does work in Chrome on a Windows Computer, but not on my Macbook Pro

```
*edit*
```

I have tried several variations of the `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` headers to no avail.

When I leave out all headers, I get just a string in the browser: `"id,name,email"` (no download).

Do I need some kind of special header for Chrome to let me me force a download of this streamed data?

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

Route::get('test-csv', function(){

        $response = new StreamedResponse(function(){
            // Open output stream
            $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            fputcsv($handle, [
                'id',
                'name',
                'email'
            ]);
            fclose($handle);

        }, 200, [
            'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment;filename=export.csv;',
        ]);


        return $response;
    });
```

Comment: Just tested this in OSX Yosemite with Chrome 46, so it works on a Mac (at least on the latest software versions). Maybe there's something special about your Chrome setup. Try it in incognito mode, to rule out any plugin interference.

Comment: Thank you for helping me narrow this down; it looks like it is just my browser.  I had someone else on a Mac test it on Chrome and it works for them also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bogdan's comment made me realize that the problem must have been in my install/settings in Chrome.

I turned off extensions and uninstalled and reinstalled chrome.  It is working as expected now.

If @bogdan wants to post his comment/suggestion as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.